# Installing plugin files

Tags: visual-studio, file, plugins

I am trying to download a plugin, Twitter Bootstrap - Multi Select, and have downloaded the zip file.

The zip file contains:

```
Css (file folder) ........
Fonts (file folder).........
js (file folder).........
less (file folder)........
.gitignore (GITIGNORE FILE).......
bower.json JSON FILE........
index   HTML Document........
README.md   MD File........
tests    HTML DOCUMENT.......
```

How do I go about adding this to my project? Do I have to add each folder individually? How do I include it in my project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the instructions in ReadMe. What project is it? What have you tried to do and what problem do you see when you try to add the root folder?

Comment: Check out [Snazz Up Your MVC Apps with Twitter Bootstrap: A Get-Started Guide](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/twitter-bootstrap.aspx).

Comment: That's great! Thanks. Twitter Bootstrap Multi Select doesn't exist as a Nuget package so I have to add the files manually to my project, which is difficult. Is it possible to simply add the root file somewhere?